# flow of ios app using Corelocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I was wondering if anyone can explain the flow of an app using core location.  I am building a GPS app that will pause (after a given delay set by the user) and then run through the iterations (also set by the user).  But I am finding that it runs indefinitely.  If I take the for loop out of the code I then get 2 responses back from location manager on my first search.

Effectively this is: user presses the "get location" button.  This then calls our getlocation function but it loops twice through this and through the NSLog output I will always see 2 responses but only on the first loop.

Comment: Could you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting location updates is an asynchronous project and you need to wait for, then filter the results. The flow is:

Create a location manager and set your object as it's delegate.
Ask it to start updating your location
Return.

Then you will start receiving location updates. The first one will probably be "stale" (the timestamp on it will be from the last time the GPS was active.) Make your code reject any location update who's timestamp is more than 1/2 second greater than now to solve this problem.

Next, you will receive a series of location updates with really bad (unacceptably bad) horizontal accuracy readings. Check the accuracy reading and reject all readings that are not accurate enough for your purposes. (The accuracy reading is actually a radius value that defines a circle where the location might be, expressed in meters. Smaller is better.)

How accurate is accurate enough depends on your needs. If you can't get an accurate enough reading in a reasonable time (say 30 seconds) make sure you code a timeout that gives up and displays a "can't get an accurate reading" message to the user.

Once you either get a recent reading that's accurate enough, or time out, stop updating until the next time you need a location fix (or keep updating if your app requires that.)

You might want to write a test app that displays timestamps, map positions, accuracy readings, etc as they come in, and then walk around with your phone while it's running. It takes a fair amount of tinkering to get an algorithm that filters location updates the way you need it to.

Comment: I guess I was more looking for the flow through the program and the various functions I am using to set it up.  I know that viewDidLoad is first.  But within objective-c does the flow of a program go top to bottom or do certain functions present before others.  For instance, if I call the allocation and delegate for the CLLocation module am I then immediately going to the locationManager function or will the program move through the rest of the program first.